Dynamically updating layers in mapbox gl within RMarkdown HTML document (Uncaught TypeError)
I'm rendering a mapboxgl map in RMarkdown (HTML output, using r2d3 js library in R for the js part). I'm trying to update the layers displayed in a mapboxgl map by passing in a dynamic variable for the map fill property (based on what the user selects in a dropdown).
//set default property for map so it knows which field to use for the map fill color  
var dropdown_val = 'ODpc'

//function that initially draws the map   
function loadMap(dropdown_val) {
    
    map2.on('load', function () {
    map2.addSource('bb', { type: 'geojson', data: data, generateId: true});
    map2.addLayer({
      'id': 'berlin',
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'bb',
      'paint': {
        'fill-color': {
            'property': dropdown_val,
            'stops': [[break1, '#feebe2'], [break2, '#fbb4b9'], [break3, '#f768a1'], [break4, '#c51b8a'], [break5, '#7a0177']]
          },
        'fill-opacity': .65
          }
    });
    map2.addLayer({
      'id': 'berlin-stroke',
      'type': 'line',
      'source': 'bb',
      'paint': {
        'line-color': '#000',
        'line-width': [
          'case',
          ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
          2,
          .5
          ]
      }
    });
});
  
  
}

loadMap(dropdown_val)


//call the function that adds the year dropdown, other map elements like legend, etc.
document.body.onload = addElement;


function addElement() {
  
  //Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["2014-2022", "2022","2021","2020","2019", "2018", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"];
  var val_array = ["ODpc", "ODpc2022","ODpc2021","ODpc2020","ODpc2019", "ODpc2018", "ODpc2017", "ODpc2016", "ODpc2015", "ODpc2014"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  selectList.className = "mySelect";


  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = val_array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }

  //make legend etc.. etc...

});

 // create a function that gets the current value of the dropdown
 document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function(){
  
     dropdown_val = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
     return dropdown_val
  
}

This works as expected - the initial map renders fine, and I can return the current dropdown value as expected.
My issue: I want to dynamically update the map based on the current value of the dropdown. When I add the document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange event listener, which updates the map based on the dropdown value, I run into problems:
//set default property for map so it knows which field to use for the map fill color  
var dropdown_val = 'ODpc'

//function that initially draws the map   
function loadMap(dropdown_val) {
    
    map2.on('load', function () {
    map2.addSource('bb', { type: 'geojson', data: data, generateId: true});
    map2.addLayer({
      'id': 'berlin',
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'bb',
      'paint': {
        'fill-color': {
            'property': dropdown_val,
            'stops': [[break1, '#feebe2'], [break2, '#fbb4b9'], [break3, '#f768a1'], [break4, '#c51b8a'], [break5, '#7a0177']]
          },
        'fill-opacity': .65
          }
    });
    map2.addLayer({
      'id': 'berlin-stroke',
      'type': 'line',
      'source': 'bb',
      'paint': {
        'line-color': '#000',
        'line-width': [
          'case',
          ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
          2,
          .5
          ]
      }
    });
});
  
  
}

loadMap(dropdown_val)


//call the function that adds the year dropdown, other map elements like legend, etc.
document.body.onload = addElement;


function addElement() {
  
  //Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["2014-2022", "2022","2021","2020","2019", "2018", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"];
  var val_array = ["ODpc", "ODpc2022","ODpc2021","ODpc2020","ODpc2019", "ODpc2018", "ODpc2017", "ODpc2016", "ODpc2015", "ODpc2014"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  selectList.className = "mySelect";


  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = val_array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }

  //make legend etc.. etc...

});

//update the map  based on the dropdown value
$(document).ready(function() {

 document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function(){
  

    //remove any existing layers so that they can be re-drawn according to whatever the user has selected in dropdown
    if (map2.getLayer('berlin')) {
        map2.removeLayer('berlin');
      }
    if (map2.getLayer('berlin-stroke')) {
       map2.removeLayer('berlin-stroke');
    }
    if (map2.getLayer(dropdown_val)) {
       map2.removeLayer(dropdown_val);
    }
    if (map2.getLayer('stroke')) {
       map2.removeLayer('stroke');
    }
       
   dropdown_val = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;

   //call function to load in current dropdown value and re-draw map fill to be based on that property
   map2.addLayer({
      'id': dropdown_val,
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'bb',
      'paint': {
      'fill-color': {
          'property': 'ODpc'+dropdown_val,
          'stops': [[break1, '#feebe2'], [break2, '#fbb4b9'], [break3, '#f768a1'], [break4, '#c51b8a'], [break5, '#7a0177']]
        },
      'fill-opacity': .65
        }
  });
   map2.addLayer({
     'id': 'stroke',
     'type': 'line',
     'source': 'bb',
     'paint': {
        'line-color': '#000',
        'line-width': [
           'case',
           ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
          2,
          .5
          ]
       }
    })     
  }
})

At the line document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function() I get an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onchange')

The map actually does update with the onchange function, it's just glitchy and sometimes doesn't work depending on how the page loads.
It seems the error might be due to the onchange function being called before the dropdown is actually rendered in the DOM?  But, if I move the onchange function INSIDE the addElement() function, which is called on document.body.onload , it doesn't work at all (I don't get an error message, but the map layers are not removed and re-drawn).

There isn't enough information in your question to answer it. It's best to make your question reproducible.  Since I don't have all the information, it's really hard to help. You could edit your question to make it reproducible, in the meantime tighten up a few small issues in your JS:  function addElement() { in both sets of code. You've added the closing });  - but there shouldn't be a parenthesis here.  Additionally, each line of code needs to be closed to prevent issues (other than those that end with {).  For ex. the ; is missing at the end of var dropdown_val = 'ODpc'.

Now, this is a wild guess, but if you create the dropdown and subscribe to it in the map2 load function instead, there shouldn't be a race condition.
//set default property for map so it knows which field to use for the map fill color  
var dropdown_val = 'ODpc'

//function that initially draws the map   
function loadMap(dropdown_val) {
  map2.on('load', function () {
    // Add source and layers, etc...

    // Create and inside the load function instead.
    addElement();
  });
}

loadMap(dropdown_val)

function addElement() {
  //Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["2014-2022", "2022","2021","2020","2019", "2018", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"];
  var val_array = ["ODpc", "ODpc2022","ODpc2021","ODpc2020","ODpc2019", "ODpc2018", "ODpc2017", "ODpc2016", "ODpc2015", "ODpc2014"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  selectList.className = "mySelect";


  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = val_array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }

  //make legend etc.. etc...

  // Connect the event listener
  selectList.addEventListener('change', onChange);

  // Add the element where you want it, for example body.
  body.appendChild(selectList)
};

function onChange(event) {
  const dropdown_val = event.target.value;
  // Update the layers depending on the value
}


still duplicating, even with your solution :(

I'm not sure what you mean by "still duplicating". Do you mean that the layers are not removed from the map, so you get the same layer multiple times when changing the value in the dropdown?
